# Limitar el numero de caracteres de un input, segun su ancho

Tags: javascript, html5

gracias de antemano por la ayuda. Nesecito una funcion JavaScript que permita limitar el numero de caracteres permitidos en un input, segun su ancho. Esto por que con el atributo `maxlength` no me es suficiente, explico por que. Por ejemplo, tengo un input con un Width de 150px, yo quiero que cuando la cadena de texto haya abarcado el tamaño del input ya no se ha permitido escribir otro caracteres.

```html
<input type="text" style="width:150px;" maxlength="10">
```

En siguiente codigo puede probar que si escribe "hola hola hola" limitara a 10 caracteres y la cadena de texto abarcara menos de la mitad del input. En cambio. si escribe 10 veces w la cadena abarcara mas de la mitad del input. La solucion a este problema seria alguna funcion JS que permita limitar el numero de caracteres dentro del input cuando la cadena de texto abarque el 100% del tamaño del input. Gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Utilizá el método Canvas.MeasureText de HTML5.

https://www.w3schools.com/tags/canvas_measuretext.asp

Con esto medís el ancho de un texto en pantalla. Agregás oninput="revisar()" y revisas que no exceda el maximo del width.

El ejemplo lo medi a ojo, tendrías que colocar la medida justa de 150px.

```js
var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
    var d = document.getElementById("myInput");
    var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
    ctx.font = "30px Arial";


    function revisar(){
        var txt = d.value;

        if(ctx.measureText(txt).width>363.5) 
            d.value = txt.substring(0, txt.length - 1);

    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>

  <input id="myInput" width="300" height="150" oninput="revisar()">
  <canvas id="myCanvas" width="0" height="0" style="display:none;"></canvas>

  </body>
</html>
```

Saludos.

Comment: Hola, gracias por responder. Este metodo es para un canvas, podrias mostrarme una funcion utilizandolo con un input, por favor.

Comment: Ya te añadi un ejemplo. No se me ocurre otra forma sin usar canvas. Pero no es complicado, lo ocultas.